# Add days to datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

My data set contains multiple columns of sales-related data. I have `ORDEREDDATE` and `SHIPPINGDAYS` in the DataFrame. I want to add a new column named `DELIVEREDDATE` in the dataset.

**Current DataFrame**

```
ORDEREDDATE     SHIPPINGDAYS 
2018-5-13           6
2017-8-24           4
2018-6-1            2
```

**Expected output**

```
ORDEREDDATE     SHIPPINGDAYS   DELIVEREDDATE
2018-5-13           6              2018-5-19
2017-8-24           4              2017-8-28
2018-6-1            2              2018-6-3
```

**Types**

```
ORDEREDDATE          object
SHIPPINGDAYS         object
```

**Attempt to solve**

```
df1['DELIVERYDATE'] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(df1['ORDEREDDATE'].astype(str), '%Y-%m-%d') + datetime.timedelta(df1['SHIPPINGDAYS'].astype(str).astype(int))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
# make sure types are correct format
df['ORDEREDDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ORDEREDDATE'])
df['SHIPPINGDAYS'] = df['SHIPPINGDAYS'].astype(int)

df['DELIVEREDDATE'] = (df
                      .apply(lambda x: x['ORDEREDDATE'] + pd.Timedelta(days= x['SHIPPINGDAYS']), 
                       axis=1)

  ORDEREDDATE  SHIPPINGDAYS DELIVEREDDATE
0  2018-05-13             6    2018-05-19
1  2017-08-24             4    2017-08-28
2  2018-06-01             2    2018-06-03
```

Comment: I tried the code you shared. `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: make sure the types are correct. what is `SHIPPINGDAYS` & `ORDEREDATE` type?

Comment: Both are object type.

Comment: The EOF makes me think you copy pasted something wrong, missing a parenthesys or something.

Comment: I don't think you need to include the `x['ORDEREDDATE']` in the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to transform the column into a datetime object:

```
df1['ORDEREDDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['ORDEREDDATE']
```

Then you define your new column while also turning the `int` values from `SHIPPINGDAYS` to timedelta objects. That way you can sum these objects returning the desired output:

```
df['DELIVEREDDATE'] = df['ORDEREDDATE'] + df['SHIPPINGDAYS'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x,unit='D'))
```

Output:

```
  ORDEREDDATE  SHIPPINGDAYS DELIVEREDDATE
0  2018-05-13             6    2018-05-19
1  2017-08-24             4    2017-08-28
2  2018-06-01             2    2018-06-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding seconds, not days!

You may initialize `timedelta` with names `days` argument. If you won't provide name, it assumes *seconds*.

Also, you end with `datetime` object, so you need to format it the way you want after calculation is done.